# Amount in Words prints values as ones after the decimal point - PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP function to print amounts in words, It works fine till the decimal, but the later decimal point, it prints the value as of in one's place.

Like, if the value is "54.35", it prints "Fifty-Four Three Five" Instead, it should print like "Fifty Four Thirty-Five".

The code goes as :

```
function getIndianCurrency(float $number)
    {
    $decimal = round($number - ($no = floor($number)), 2) * 100;
    $hundred = null;
    $digits_length = strlen($no);
    $i = 0;
    $str = array();
    $words = array(0 => '', 1 => 'One', 2 => 'Two',
    3 => 'Three', 4 => 'Four', 5 => 'Five', 6 => 'Six',
    7 => 'Seven', 8 => 'Eight', 9 => 'Nine',
    10 => 'Ten', 11 => 'Eleven', 12 => 'Twelve',
    13 => 'Thirteen', 14 => 'Fourteen', 15 => 'Fifteen',
    16 => 'Sixteen', 17 => 'Seventeen', 18 => 'Eighteen',
    19 => 'Nineteen', 20 => 'Twenty', 30 => 'Thirty',
    40 => 'Forty', 50 => 'Fifty', 60 => 'Sixty',
    70 => 'Seventy', 80 => 'Eighty', 90 => 'Ninety');
    $digits = array('', 'Hundred','Thousand','Lakh', 'Crore');
        while( $i < $digits_length ) {
        $divider = ($i == 2) ? 10 : 100;
        $number = floor($no % $divider);
        $no = floor($no / $divider);
        $i += $divider == 10 ? 1 : 2;
        if ($number) {
            $plural = (($counter = count($str)) && $number > 9) ? 's' : null;
            $hundred = ($counter == 1 && $str[0]) ? ' and ' : null;
            $str [] = ($number < 21) ? $words[$number].' '. $digits[$counter]. $plural.' '.$hundred:$words[floor($number / 10) * 10].' '.$words[$number % 10]. ' '.$digits[$counter].$plural.' '.$hundred;
        } else $str[] = null;
    }
    $Rupees = implode('', array_reverse($str));
    $paise = ($decimal > 0) ? ($words[$decimal / 10] . " " . $words[$decimal % 10]) . ' Paise' : '';
    return ($Rupees ? $Rupees . 'Rupees ' : '') . $paise;
}


getIndianCurrency(54.35);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need another loop to process `$decimal`, just like you do for `$no`.

Comment: I suggest you move loop that into another function. Then you can call it for the part before the decimal and again for the part after the decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your expected output by this.

```
<?php
function getCurrencyString( $amount ){
    $hundred = null;
    $digits_length = strlen($amount);
    $i = 0;
    $str = array();
    $words = array(0 => '', 1 => 'One', 2 => 'Two',
    3 => 'Three', 4 => 'Four', 5 => 'Five', 6 => 'Six',
    7 => 'Seven', 8 => 'Eight', 9 => 'Nine',
    10 => 'Ten', 11 => 'Eleven', 12 => 'Twelve',
    13 => 'Thirteen', 14 => 'Fourteen', 15 => 'Fifteen',
    16 => 'Sixteen', 17 => 'Seventeen', 18 => 'Eighteen',
    19 => 'Nineteen', 20 => 'Twenty', 30 => 'Thirty',
    40 => 'Forty', 50 => 'Fifty', 60 => 'Sixty',
    70 => 'Seventy', 80 => 'Eighty', 90 => 'Ninety');
    $digits = array('', 'Hundred','Thousand','Lakh', 'Crore');
        while( $i < $digits_length ) {
        $divider = ($i == 2) ? 10 : 100;
        $number = floor($amount % $divider);
        $amount = floor($amount / $divider);
        $i += $divider == 10 ? 1 : 2;
        if ($number) {
            $plural = (($counter = count($str)) && $number > 9) ? 's' : null;
            $hundred = ($counter == 1 && $str[0]) ? ' and ' : null;
            $str [] = ($number < 21) ? $words[$number].' '. $digits[$counter]. $plural.' '.$hundred:$words[floor($number / 10) * 10].' '.$words[$number % 10]. ' '.$digits[$counter].$plural.' '.$hundred;
        } else $str[] = null;
    }
    return implode('', array_reverse($str));
}
function getIndianCurrency(float $number){
    $decimal = round($number - ($no = floor($number)), 2) * 100;
    $Rupees = getCurrencyString( $no );

    $paise = ($decimal > 0) ? getCurrencyString( $decimal ) . ' Paise' : '';
    return ($Rupees ? $Rupees . 'Rupees ' : '') . $paise;
}

echo getIndianCurrency( 54.35 );
```

Output :

```
Fifty Four Rupees Thirty Five Paise
```